# Truth Tables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, truthtable

I'm currently implementing a Master Save behaviour for a master layout that holds 7 tabs.

Essentially, when the Save button on the master layout is clicked, I want it so that each tab saves itself (complete), and then reports to the master layout that it has saved (again, complete)

What I am stuck on is, I'd like to have a truth table in the corresponding JS file for the master layout, which keeps track of which of the 7 tabs have been saved so it can report back to the user that the save has completed.

**To generalise: Truth tables/2D arrays in Javascript, where they at?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "2D arrays in JS, where they at?" Do you understand how to create a 2D 
array?

Comment: Not a matter of being too colloquial, but is your search hand broken? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+2d+array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of whether each of the 7 tabs has been saved with an array of booleans:

```
var tabSaveTable = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
```

Then, whenever a given tab is saved, you can just mark its slot as `true` and whenever it is changed (so it needs to be saved again), its slot can be set to `false`.  For example to mark tab3 as saved (assuming your tabs are numbered starting with 0), you would just set:

```
tabSaveTable[3] = true;
```

If tab3 gets changed and needs saving again, you would set:

```
tabSaveTable[3] = false;
```

This is the part of your question that I think I followed.  If there is more to it, please clarify.  I don't understand why you would need a 2D array for this.

Comment: This works too, I was just thinking 2D array to make things a bit more readable. Something like:
  
tabSaveTable["name_of_tab"] = false;
  
But this works too to be honest, thanks!

Comment: @cswilby - you can do it that way too.  That's not a 2D array.  You don't use an array for that construct.  You use a javascript object with named properties.